# ORA-06502 error for testing existing values

Tags: plsql, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

Here is the procedure and the error the value I am sending the exactly the value which is already existing in the table(have no dependencies).Not sure why the it is throwing the error.

```
 create or replace PROCEDURE TEST (email_address in VARCHAR2, 
 CatItype in VARCHAR2, opt_status in CHAR,userIns in VARCHAR2,
 editstat out VARCHAR2) 
 AS
 eid EMAILDATA.EMAIL_ID%TYPE;
 eid1 EMAILDATA.EMAIL_ID%TYPE;
 cid EMAILDATA.category_id%TYPE;
 cname EMAILDATA.CATEGORY_NAME%TYPE;
 pref EMAILDATA.PREFERENCE%TYPE;

 Email_val EMAILDATA.EMAIL_ADDRESS%TYPE := email_address;
 CatIntType EMAILDATA.INTER_CONTACTTYPE%TYPE := CatItype;
 usrins EMAILDATA.USER_INSERTING%TYPE := userIns;
 ostat EMAILDATA.PREFERENCE%TYPE := opt_status;
 error_flag BOOLEAN ;

  Error
  ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small
  ORA-06512: at "TEST", line 19
  ORA-06512: at line 13
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the problem is here: `usrins EMAILDATA.USER_INSERTING%TYPE := userIns;`

The max length of VARCHAR2 in SQL (table type) = 4000 characters

The max length in PL/SQL IS 32767

**USER_INSERTING** is a column in the table EMAILDATA. I suppose it has VARCHAR2 type. In this case the max. number of characters for this variable is limited to 4000 (depending on your DDL).

**userIns** is a PL/SQL VARCHAR2 variable which can contain up to 32767 characters.

Comment: userins column is varchar2(50 byte). Tried to change the `userIns in VARCHAR2(50)` but it is giving error as **Error(6,21): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "(" when expecting one of the following:     := . ) , @ % default character The symbol ":=" was substituted for "(" to continue. **

Comment: @SMITH You cannot set the length for VARCHAR2 in the procedure definition. What do you want to achieve? Someone called your procedure with a long userIns so the error occured. I think it's natural. As a variant you can ignore the rest of the userIns:  usrins EMAILDATA.USER_INSERTING%TYPE := substr(userIns,1,50);

Comment: @SMITH In this case the procedure will work but you'll never know if someone enters the wrong data